# data format gets converted unexpectedly from dd/mm/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have a userForm to collect some data to be inserted in a excel worksheet.
One of the field is a date and for my locale dates are always dd/mm/yyyy.

I put a date (i.e. 13/08/2018) in the form and debugging the code I see:

```
data_mov = new_mov.data.Value
```

the value is taken from the form as I wrote it. So it is still 13/08/2018. This evaluates to 13/08/2018 = 13/08/2018

Then I put the value in a specific cell. Debugging i see that

```
Range("A" & riga).Value = data_mov
```

evaluates to 08/13/2018 = 13/08/2018

So the cell stores 08/02/2018. Why does it happen? I have no intermediate code that can manipulate the date. How can I prevent this to happen?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could choose sample dates that had a day value or 13 or higher to make it clear which date is which.

Comment: true. editing for clearness.

Comment: What type of variable is `data_mov`?

Comment: i don't declare the variables. I'm coming from a language (PHP) where this is not necessary. What type should i use?

Comment: _I'm coming from a language (PHP) where this is not necessary_ It is not necessary in VBA also, but it helps solving issues like that. What is `new_mov.data`?

Comment: it is the field in the user form (user form is new_mov and field is data) where I input the date

Comment: So I assume the _field_ is a TextBox? If so, data_mov is Variant/String. If `"A" & riga` cell is formatted as General, then data_mov should be converted to date. Now if the cell contains date, it is not `08/13/2018` or `13/08/2018` but a number of days since `1899-12-31`. What you see in cell or debugger depends on cell format and regional settings.

Comment: @BrakNicku the regional settings (already checked) are to store dates as dd/mm/yyyy. This is what I don't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this line to your code:

```
Range("A" & riga).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"
```

It will apply desired formatting to your cell.

Alternatively you can use:

```
Cells(riga, 1).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"
```

Comment: adding this just after `Range("A" & riga).Value = data_mov` doesn't change anything

Comment: It should change, it is the format changing method, can you recheck please or try the other one?

Comment: @LelioFaieta what is the desired format you are aiming for?

Comment: i'm looking to keep exactly the string as it was inserted in the input.